# How to implement tags in webapp?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, tags

I am trying to make a basic quotation-sharing app using Webapp. Obviously it is crucial to be able to give arbitrary tags to each quote.

So here are the relevant code that I've come up with:
(Mostly from the example chat app in the great introductory book '[Using Google App Engine](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801601.do)' )

```
class Quote(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty()
  text = db.StringProperty()
  tags = db.StringListProperty()
  created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

And the 'view':

```
class QuoteHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    que = db.Query(Quote).order('-created');
    chat_list = que.fetch(limit=10)
    doRender(
          self,
          'quote.htm',
          { 'quote_list': quote_list })

  def post(self):
    self.session = Session()
    if not 'userkey' in self.session:
      doRender(self, 'quote.htm', {'error' : 'Must be logged in'} )
      return

    msg = self.request.get('message')
    if msg == '':
      doRender(self,'quote.htm',{'error' : 'Blank quote ignored'} )
      return
    tgs = self.request.get('tags') #really not sure of this
    newq = Quote(user = self.session['userkey'], text=msg, tags= tgs)
    newq.put();
    self.get();
```

And in quote.htm I have:

```
{% extends "_base.htm" %}
{% block bodycontent %}
      <h1>Quotes</h1>
      <p>
      <form method="post" action="/quote">
        Quote:<input type="text" name="message" size="60"/><br />
        Tags: <input type="text" name="tags" size="30"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Send"/> 
      </form>
      </p>
      {% ifnotequal error None %}
       <p>
       {{ error }}
       </p>
      {% endifnotequal %}
<br />
<h3> The latest quotes </h3>

      {% for quote in quote_list %}
        <p>
           {{ quote.text }}<br />
         ({{quote.user.account}}) <br />
         {{ quote.tags }}

           {{ quote.created|date:"D d M Y" }}
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, this combo is faulty. I get:

> BadValueError: Property tags must be a list

No matter what I enter in the tags filed, and (obviously) I am new to both Python and Webapp. I googled a lot but could not find any guide to implement tags. So I really appreciate your help to fix this error, or rather point me to a a more elegant way to deal with tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `split()` to turn `tgs` into a list of words before creating your `Quote`. Tags should be separated by whitespace in your form, otherwise you can add an argument to `split` if you'd rather separate them by something else.

```
...
tgs = self.request.get('tags').split()
newq = Quote(user = self.session['userkey'], text=msg, tags= tgs)
...
```

Comment: Great, the error is gone by adding split(), but now the tags are rendered in brackets like : [u'pet', u'love']. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you just need to modify your template to loop over the tags (similar to how you loop over the quotes) and output each tag separately.

Comment: You are right. This worked {%for tag in chat.tags %}{{ tag }}{% endfor %} Many thanks.

Comment: On second thought, it's probably much better to use something like `{{ quote.tags|join:", " }}`.

Comment: Again, you are right. this filter is aesthetically (and perhaps performance-wise) a better solution.